# Is it possible to sign a certificate programmatically in a browser

Tags: java, javascript, security, certificate

Is it possible to sign a document with a client certificate programmatically in a browser using either java or javascript WITHOUT user intervention ? Could a hacker use this to impersonate a user ?

If not does it mean it is less secure to make client sign a document by delegating to a server than sign on his own machine ?

Comment: what do you mean by "sign a certificate"?  one usually uses a private certificate to sign other things.  to answer your other question, your trust is only as strong as the protection of your secret.

Comment: You might mean "accept a certificate" for which the answer is No. If that could be done programmatically it would be anarchy!

Comment: Oops sorry I meant "to sign a DOCUMENT with a client certificate programmatically"

Comment: If you find a way, please send details to secalert_us.

Comment: @tom so it means it's not possible ;)

Comment: @user310291 "Not" is a bit strong. Certainly shouldn't be (in an unconstrained way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, by using Javascript. Called "WebCrypto", its support depends on the browser. For example, Chrome's support for WebCrypto features is listed here:

https://www.chromium.org/blink/webcrypto

Please take time to correct the question. It should be "Is it possible to sign programmatically in a browser." This is because the cryptographic action of **"signing a certificate"** actually exists and is used to prove a certificate is genuine, whose private key in turn can be used to **"signing a document"** to prove the document is genuine, forming a chain of trust.